# Spring JMX- turning pojo into JMX bean, value not visible in jconsole

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-jmx

Consider the following pojo.

```
public class UserJMXBean {

private static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void addUser(User user){
   userList.add(user);
}

public static List<User> getUserList() {
    return userList;
}

public static void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
    UserJMXBean.userList = userList;
}
}
```

I have mapped this class as follows :

```
<bean class="com.mincom.util.deployment.MineStarPropertyConfigurer"/>

<bean id="userJMXBean"
      class="minestar.platform.domain.user.UserJMXBean"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="bean:name=UserJMXBean" value-ref="userJMXBean"/>
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

While debugging the pojo class I am getting my values of userlist but not when looking through jconsole. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see anything JMX related in that bean also i doubt static methods are available in the JMX console.

Comment: @M.Deinum Spring has a MBeanExpoter through which you can convert pojo to JMX. Here is the link [link](http://noushinb.blogspot.in/2011/02/spring-3-jmx.html)

Comment: Trust me I known Spring (having written 2 books about it). The default config for the `MBeanExporter` exposes attributes, however your bean doesn't have any attributes only static methods. Your methods should be non static to be exposed.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok. Sorry, I didn't knew that... So, if I keep my methods non static the userList value will be exposed. 
I would also like to add that this is a standalone JVM server. It does not run on any app server. Will this work too?

Comment: Why would there be a difference... It is all inside a JVM... JMX is JMX.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any other workaround. For some reason I need it to be static. As my other client jvm does not work without making it static..

Comment: Not that I'm aware of JMX only supports attributes and operations on the object. Not static operations on the type.

Comment: @M.Deinum Got it Denium. I changed it to non static somehow and got the answer. If you can write an answer then I can mark it as answered.